# how to extract onclick in Hpricot ruby

Tags: ruby, hpricot

i want to get the parentID from this.

```
<div class="module-head" onclick="getURL('/DU/initAction.do?parentId=1063&categoryType=6')"></div>
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: You might like to switch to nokogiri. Hpricot was abandoned several years back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup:

```
html = <<-EOF
<div class="module-head" onclick="getURL('/DU/initAction.do?parentId=1063&categoryType=6')"></div>
EOF
```

Hpricot:

```
doc = Hpricot html
```

or Nokogiri:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML html
```

Interestingly, it's the same in both:

```
doc.at('div')[:onclick][/parentId=(\d+)/, 1]
#=> "1063"
```